# gearman function in worker remains undefined

Tags: python, gearman

I have pretty simple code of worker, might be doing some silly mistake.

```
class BingWorker(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.gm_worker = gearman.GearmanWorker(['localhost:4730'])
        completed_job_request = self.gm_worker.register_task('bingmedia', callBing)

    def callBing(self, gearman_worker, gearman_job):
        print "In worker ", gearman_job.data
        return "Kools"

    def run(self):
        self.gm_worker.work()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BingWorker().run()
```

gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "worker.py", line 16, in <module>
    BingWorker().run()
  File "worker.py", line 6, in __init__
    completed_job_request = self.gm_worker.register_task('bingmedia', callBing)
NameError: global name 'callBing' is not defined
```

any hints? example is very similar to python example at http://gearman.org/examples/reverse/. just put in class structure

**Improved code:**

```
class BingWorker(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.gm_worker = gearman.GearmanWorker(['localhost:4730'])

    def callBing(self, gearman_worker, gearman_job):
        print "In worker ", gearman_job.data
        return "Kools"

    def run(self):
        completed_job_request = self.gm_worker.register_task('bingmedia', self.callBing)
        self.gm_worker.work()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BingWorker().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `callBing` to `self.callBing` and it might be better to move the registration to the first line of the run method rather than the `__init__` method.

The fist is because `callBing` is a reference to a *missing* global while `self.callBing` is a reference to the classes method. The second is because potentially you could get a call to `self.callBing` before **init** has finished which would be bad news.

Comment: The updated code looks better apart from the lack of `docstrings` The real question is does it now do what you were expecting it to do?

Comment: Yes, it does as expected